# How to return all duplicates rows in same columns in laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, duplicates

I want to get all the list of jobseekers which is the same fullname and country,
in **Jobseekers Table**,

```
**id** |fullname    |country    |phone_number

1      |John        | singapore |0988884434

2      |john        | singapore |0933333333

3      |Michael     |Malaysia   |0888888888

4      |Smith       |Dubai      |082388888888

5      |Smith       |Dubai      |03939494944
```

what am I expect here is,

```
john  |singapore
john  |singapore
Smith |Dubai
Smith |Dubai
```

this is what i tried here,

```
 $duplicates = DB::table('jobseekers')
                ->select(array('jobseekers.fullname','jobseekers.country', DB::raw('COUNT('*')'))
                ->groupBy('jobseekers.fullname','jobseekers.country')
            ->having(DB::raw('COUNT('*')'))
                ->get();
       var_dump($duplicates);
```

Any help or advice you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$duplicates = DB::table('jobseekers')
    ->select('fullname','country', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
    ->groupBy('fullname', 'country')
    ->having('count', '>', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: sir, its showing like "
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country' in 'field list' (SQL: select `fullname`, `country`, 0 from `jobseekers` group by `fullname`, `country` having `count` > 1)"

Comment: @ThanHtutOo I don't know why `country` is an "Unknown column", But I just fixed another error which I copied from your code (`COUNT('*')` should be `COUNT(*)`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `INNER` query to get the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT fullname, country
FROM jobseekers
WHERE fullname IN (
    SELECT fullname
    FROM jobseekers
    GROUP BY fullname
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```